# Gmail API decoding messages in Javascript

Tags: javascript, email, character-encoding, decoding, gmail-api

I am having serious problems decoding the message body of the emails I get using the Gmail API. I want to grab the message content and put the content in a div. I am using a base64 decoder, which I know won't decode emails encoded differently, but I am not sure how to check an email to decide which decoder to use -- emails that say they are utf-8 encoded are successfully decoded by the base64 decoder, but not be a utf-8 decoder.

I've been researching email decoding for several days now, and I've learned that I am a little out of my league here. I haven't done much work with coding around email before. Here is the code I am using to get the emails:

```
gapi.client.load('gmail', 'v1', function() {
var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.list({
  labelIds: ['INBOX']
});
request.execute(function(resp) {
  document.getElementById('email-announcement').innerHTML = '<i>Hello! I am reading your <b>inbox</b> emails.</i><br><br>------<br>';
  var content = document.getElementById("message-list");
  if (resp.messages == null) {
    content.innerHTML = "<b>Your inbox is empty.</b>";
  } else {
    var encodings = 0;
    content.innerHTML = "";
    angular.forEach(resp.messages, function(message) {
      var email = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
      'id': message.id
      });
      email.execute(function(stuff) {
        if (stuff.payload == null) {
          console.log("Payload null: " + message.id);
        }
        var header = "";
        var sender = "";
        angular.forEach(stuff.payload.headers, function(item) {
          if (item.name == "Subject") {
            header = item.value;
          }
          if (item.name == "From") {
            sender = item.value;
          }
        })
        try {
          var contents = "";
          if (stuff.payload.parts == null) {
            contents = base64.decode(stuff.payload.body.data);
          } else {
            contents = base64.decode(stuff.payload.parts[0].body.data);
          }
          content.innerHTML += '<b>Subject: ' + header + '</b><br>';
          content.innerHTML += '<b>From: ' + sender + '</b><br>';
          content.innerHTML += contents + "<br><br>";
        } catch (err) {
          console.log("Encoding error: " + encodings++);
        }
      })
    })
  }
 });
});
```

I was performing some checks and debugging, so there's leftover `console.log`'s and some other things that are only there for testing. Still, you can see here what I am trying to do.

What is the best way to decode the emails I pull from the Gmail API? Should I try to put the emails into `<script>`'s with `charset` and `type` attributes matching the encoding content of the email? I believe I remember charset only works with a `src` attribute, which I wouldn't have here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

For a prototype app I'm writing, the following code is working for me:

```
var base64 = require('js-base64').Base64;
// js-base64 is working fine for me.

var bodyData = message.payload.body.data;
// Simplified code: you'd need to check for multipart.

base64.decode(bodyData.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'));
// If you're going to use a different library other than js-base64,
// you may need to replace some characters before passing it to the decoder.
```

Caution: these points are not explicitly documented and could be wrong:

1. The [`users.messages: get` API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#request) returns "parsed body content" by default. This data seems to be always encoded in UTF-8 and Base64, regardless of the `Content-Type` and `Content-Transfer-Encoding` header.

   For example, my code had no problem parsing an email with these headers: `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-2022-JP`, `Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit`.
2. The mapping table of the Base64 encoding [varies among various implementations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history). Gmail API uses `-` and `_` as the last two characters of the table, as defined by [RFC 4648](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4648)'s "URL and Filename safe Alphabet"<sup>1</sup>.

   Check if your Base64 library is using a different mapping table. If so, replace those characters with the ones your library accepts before passing the body to the decoder.

---

<sup>1</sup> There is one supportive line in the documentation: [the "raw" format](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#request) returns "body content as a base64url encoded string". (Thanks Eric!)

Comment: overall very good and helpful, thanks!  note that regarding point #2 it is mentioned in the users.messages.get API docs: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get  (see the format=RAW docs).  But perhaps it should be expanded further...

Comment: I have checked so many options before I found your working solution, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Use atob to decode the messages in JavaScript (see [ref](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_atob.asp)). For accessing your message payload, you can write a function:

```
var extractField = function(json, fieldName) {
  return json.payload.headers.filter(function(header) {
    return header.name === fieldName;
  })[0].value;
};
var date = extractField(response, "Date");
var subject = extractField(response, "Subject");
```

referenced from my previous [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28599753/how-to-parse-json-from-gmail-api-using-javascript) and

```
var part = message.parts.filter(function(part) {
  return part.mimeType == 'text/html';
});
var html = atob(part.body.data);
```

If the above does not decode 100% properly, the comments by @cgenco on this answer below may apply to you. In that case, do

```
var html = atob(part.body.data.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/'));
```

Comment: It looks like the `.replace(/-/g, '+').replace(/_/g, '/')` still has to be done for it to decode correctly.

Comment: @cgenco, thanks for sharing. Can you explain why it is insufficient without your `replace` functions? I will be happy to revise my answer.

Comment: per @ento's answer, Base64 encoding [varies across implementations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Implementations_and_history), and google happens to use the encoding that uses  `-` instead of `+` and `_` instead of `/`.

Answer (score 3):

I was also annoyed by this point. I discovered a solution through looking at an extension for VSCode. The solution is really simple:

```
const body = response.data.payload.body; // the base64 encoded body of a message
 body = Buffer.alloc(
        body.data.length,
        body.data,
        "base64"
      ).toString();  // the decoded message
```

It worked for me as I was using `gmail.users.messages.get()` call of Gmail API.

Comment: Could also just be `Buffer.from(body.data, 'base64').toString()`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the solution: 
Gmail API - "Users.messages: get" method has in response message.payload.body.data parted base64 data, it's separated by "-" symbol. It's not entire base64 encoded text, it's parts of base64 text. You have to try to decode every single part of this or make one mono string by unite and replace "-" symbol. After this you can easily decode it to human text.
You can manually check every part here https://www.base64decode.org

Answer (score 1):

Please use websafe decoder for decoding gmail emails and attachments. I got blank pages when I used just base64decoder, had to use this: https://www.npmjs.com/package/urlsafe-base64

Answer (score 1):

Thank @ento 's answer. I explain more why you need to replace '-' and '_' character to '+' and '/' before decode.

[Wiki Base64 Variants summary table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table) shows:

- RFC 4648 **section 4**: **base64** (standard): use '+' and '/'
- RFC 4648 **section 5**: **base64url** (URL-safe and filename-safe standard): use '-' and '_'

In short, Gmail API use **base64url** (urlsafe) format('-' and '_'), But JavaScript atob function or other
JavaScript libraries use **base64** (standard) format('+' and '/').

For Gmail API, the document says body use base64url format, see below links:

- [string/bytes type](https://developers.google.com/discovery/v1/type-format)
- [MessagePartBody](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages.attachments#MessagePartBody)
- [RAW](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/Format)

For Web atob/btoa standards, see below links:

- [The algorithm used by atob() and btoa() is specified in RFC 4648, **section 4**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Base64)
- [8.3 Base64 utility methods](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/webappapis.html#atob)
- [Forgiving base64](https://infra.spec.whatwg.org/#forgiving-base64)

Answer (score 0):

I can easily decode using another tool at https://simplycalc.com/base64-decode.php

In JS: https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64url

In Python 3:

```py
import base64
base64.urlsafe_b64decode(coded_string)
```