# Use regular expression to capture dates in utf-8

Tags: node.js, regex, utf-8

I used gmail api to get the email content and then in node.js I convert it to string.

```
Buffer.from(dataToDecode, 'base64').toString('utf8')
```

Then I use regular expression to search dates in the text. e.g. Feb 27, 2019

```
/[A-Z][a-z]{2} [0-9]{2}, [0-9]{4}/g
```

It gives no match, but when I console.log the content, the date is present. And then I copy the date to some online decoding tools, it turns out

```
\xe2\x80\x8c\x46\xe2\x80\x8c\x65\xe2\x80\x8c\x62\xe2\x80\x8c\x20\xe2\x80\x8c\x32\xe2\x80\x8c\x37\xe2\x80\x8c\x2c\xe2\x80\x8c\x20\xe2\x80\x8c\x32\xe2\x80\x8c\x30\xe2\x80\x8c\x31\xe2\x80\x8c\x39\xe2\x80\x8c\x0a
```

and

```
\x46\x65\x62\x20\x32\x37\x2c\x20\x32\x30\x31\x39
```

can both gives to the same 'Feb 27, 2019'. How to use regular expression to capture the first type encoding (i.e. the longer encoding)?

Comment: Maybe the accepted answer @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811008/gmail-api-decoding-messages-in-javascript can help you.

Comment: `\xe2\x80\x8c` is UTF-8 for [U+2080 ZERO-WIDTH NON-JOINER](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200c/index.htm). You basically just want to discard those.

Answer (score -1):

### 1. Check the [unicode table](https://unicode-table.com/en/#control-character).

### 2. Set condition:

**UTF-8: Regex Description**

`\x20`: [\s]  space

`\x2C`: [\,]  comma

`\x30-\x39`: [0-9]  digit numbers

`\x41-\x5A`: [A-Z]  Uppercase alphabetics

`\x61-\x7A`: [a-z]  lowercase alphabetics

**Pattern**

String: `Feb 27, 2019`

Regex: `/[A-Z][a-z][a-z]\s\d\d\,\s\d{4}/g`

UTF-8: `/[\x41-\x5A][\x61-\x7A]{2}\x20[\x30-\x39]+\x2C\x20[\x30-\x39]{4}/g`

[Regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/u38EV7/5)

Comment: Do anyone solve the problem to remove \xe2\x80\x8c ?