# How to get the plaintext of an email message in dart/flutter

Tags: gmail-api

Using the google apis flutter package, I get back the email message object. For example, snippet is a property of this object. It returns a short plaintext of the email message. I would like to parse the email to return a plaintext. How do I parse the email message?

```
final list = await gmailApi.users.messages.list("me", maxResults: 10, q:"subject:receipt",);
    for (var message in list.messages!) {
      final m = await gmailApi.users.messages
          .get(_currentUser!.id, message.id ?? "", format: "full"); 

      final decoded = base64Url.decode(m.payload?.body?.data ?? "");
      utf8.decode(decoded); // supposed to return plaintext (like m.snippet does) not html
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide a sample of the code ?

Comment: It could be due to the way the base64 is worked on. Have you reviewed this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24811008/gmail-api-decoding-messages-in-javascript/26085783#26085783 // We might be looking at the option to add the mimeType.